# Need update code for my program

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller code i have:

```
    <?php
    class Latest_ctrl extends Ci_controller{


        public function insert(){

            $name=$this->input->post('name');
            $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');
            $address=$this->input->post('address');
            $data=array(
                'name'=>$name,
                'pass'=>$pass,
                'email'=>$email,
                'mobile'=>$mobile,
                'address'=>$address
                );
            $this->load->model('latest_model');
             $query= $this->db->insert('form',$data);
             if($query){
                redirect('latest_ctrl/view');
             }
                }

        public function view(){
             $this->load->model('latest_model');
             $val=$this->latest_model->get_data();
              $data['value']=$val;
              $this->load->view('latest',$data);
        }
        public function index(){
    $this->load->view('new_login');
        }

        public function delete($id){
         $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
         $this->load->model('latest_model');
          $this->latest_model->delete_id($id);
          redirect(base_url('latest_ctrl/view'));

        }

        Public function update($id){
            $upd=$this->uri->segment(3);
            $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address')
            );
          $this->load->model('latest_model');

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Model code i have:

```
<?php
class Latest_model extends CI_model{


 public function insert($tableName,$data){
       return $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    }

    public function get_data(){
        $query = $this->db->get('form');
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
        $row=$query->result();
        return $row;
        }
    }

    public function delete_id($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('form'); 
    }


public function update_data(){

}
}


?>
```

view i have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<h1>Welcome Page </h1>
 <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>latest_ctrl/insert" method="post">
<table >
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 align="center"><h3>User Details</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Name'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name','value'=>'')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Pass'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'pass', 'name' => 'pass')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo form_label('Email'); ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'email', 'name' => 'email')); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo form_label('Mobile'); ?>
</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'mobile', 'name' => 'mobile')); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Address'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'address', 'name' => 'address')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

I want to edit a particular record for that purpose i need model and controller code to update the record in codeigniter.

Also I have a page which redirect the page to the update controller but i want only update code for model and controller for update purpose.

Comment: please take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Controller**
```

-> Add Construct and load model here so you can not load model in each function

```
<?php
class Latest_ctrl extends CI_controller{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('latest_model');      


}

    public function insert()
    {

        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $mobile=$this->input->post('mobile');
        $address=$this->input->post('address');
        $data=array(
          'name'=>$name,
          'pass'=>$pass,
          'email'=>$email,
          'mobile'=>$mobile,
          'address'=>$address
          );

        $id = $this->latest_model->insert($tableName="form",$data);

        if($id)
        {
            redirect('latest_ctrl/view');
        }
    }

    public function view()
    {

        $val=$this->latest_model->get_data();
        $data['value']=$val;
        $this->load->view('latest',$data);
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('new_login');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->latest_model->delete_id($id);
        redirect(base_url('latest_ctrl/view'));

    }

    Public function update($id)
    {
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address')
        );

    $this->latest_model->update_data($tableName="form",$data,$id);
    }
}
?>
```

**Model Code**

```
<?php
   class Latest_model extends CI_model{


    public function insert($tableName,$data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
        return $this->db->insert('form',$data);
    }

    public function get_data()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('form');
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
        $row=$query->result();
        return $row;
        }
    }

    public function delete_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('form'); 
    }


    public function update_data($tableName,$data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id'=>$id)
        $this->db->update($tableName, $data);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```